# 翻訳のガイドラインはありますか？

Tags: サポート, 翻訳

スタック・オーバーフロー（このサイト）の翻訳は現在、Trasifex で進められており、参加が承認されれば、翻訳の提案などが出来るようになっています。
この際の翻訳において、表記の揺れなどの防止のため、従うガイドラインは定められていますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aki さんよりチャットで回答いただき、現在は存在しないとの事です。

> ガイドラインについては聞いたことがなかったので、一旦インターナショナルチームのみなさんにも聞いてましたが、反応がなく‌​、、no response ということはガイドラインは存在しないということなのかな、と思っていたところです。
>   https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40774664#40774664
>
> ---
>
> 他の言語については、スタイルガイドは存在しないと返信がありました。（やっと！）スペインのSOだと、標準化が不可能な方言や「地域的な言い回し」があるらしく、唯‌​一のルールといえば「カジュアルなトーンで書かれている」くらいだそうです。
>   https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40864903#40864903